# Android　サーバーでのレシート検証について

Tags: android

※サーバーサイドの話になります。
このAPIでサーバーサイドでサブスクリプションの検証を行っています。
`https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/`

このAPIで`purchaseState`という値が返ってくるのですがこの値の示す意味がわかりません。
ドキュメントを読んでも一言しか書いておらず、検索しても情報が見つかりませんでした。

Googleのドキュメントでは↓のように説明されています。

```
purchaseState   integer The purchase state of the order. Possible values are:
- 0 Purchased
- 1 Canceled
- 2 Pending
```

私の疑問点は以下のとおりです。
間違っている点はありますか？

***0[Purchased]***
このステータスが返るとき、有効期限である`expiryTimeMillis`に従って
有効期限なら有償サービスを提供すべきと思っています。

***1[Canceled]***
このステータスは払い戻しを行ったときに返されると勝手に思っています。
ユーザーによる月額課金更新のキャンセルのことではなく。
そして私はこのステータスが返されるとき、自動的に`expiryTimeMillis`が過去の日付になるのではないかと思っています。
このステータスが返るとき、有償サービスの提供を取りやめるべきと思っています。

***2[Pending]***
これは保護者などによる購入の保留状態のことでしょうか？
このステータスが返るとき、有償サービスの提供を行わないのが正しいと思っています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こんにちは、サブスクリプションに関するご質問のようなので、

**Purchases.Subscriptions** の値についてということでよろしいでしょうか?

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions#resource-representations

ご質問いただいているパラメーターは **Purchases.Products** のもののようです。

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products

これはIABによる通常のアイテムの購入に関するレシートを取得するものでサブスクリプションに適用はできません。**Purchases.Subscriptions** の値をとるときは以下のAPIを利用します。

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get

この点一旦ご確認いただき、手順も含めご説明願えれば回答しやすいかと思います。

**Purchases.Products** に関する説明となりますが、

**2=Pending** は購入が、決済などなんらかの利用で一時保留されていることを表します。たとえばクレジットカードの審査に時間がかかっているとか。銀行振込での決済を行っていて、振込確認を待っているなどの状態です。決済形式(国や地域によって異なります)によっては一週間程度かかるケースもあるようです。

Comment: ありがとうございました。私の勘違いでおっしゃるとおり違うドキュメントを見ていました。